# Can we log SSIS default logging into another table

Tags: logging, ssis

Can we log SSIS default logging into another table rather than "dbo.sysssislog" table ?

Answer (score 0):

Entries to the sysssislog table are added thru the stored procedure dbo.sp_ssis_addlogentry.  I suppose you could modify this procedure to log to another table